# how to insert a value in multiple text files in command line

Tags: command-line, text-files, vi

I have 100 .txt file where i need to change the value of from 0 to 20. Is there any command line to do this, apart from doing it manually.

**The folder contains many files, out of which i need to edit only 100 files as below**

***What the file contains: the files contains values as below***

Input 1:

> 0 0.281250 0.894444 0.132812 0.108333

Input 2:

> 0 0.261450 0.544444 0.139812 0.122333
>
> 0 0.234550 0.844444 0.134812 0.109333

***How I want it to be changed:***

Output 1:

> **20** 0.281250 0.894444 0.132812 0.108333

Output 2:

> **20** 0.261450 0.544444 0.139812 0.122333
>
> **20** 0.234550 0.844444 0.134812 0.109333

Please help, since its difficult to edit all 100 files manually

Comment: You could do this with `sed`, e.g. with GNU sed `sed -E 's/\w+/20/'`. Without more detail it is hard to give a comprehensive answer

Comment: the file name is something like this :

tt_bat_\(25\).txt 

Under which , the content is:

0 0.357422 0.512500 0.158594 0.322222

0 0.357422 0.512500 0.158594 0.322222

Comment: Don't add new information in the comments, add it to the question

Comment: I have added, the same thing i have written in comment. Because of alignment its not showing properly in the comment

Answer (score 0):

I will break your question into parts

**1) How to replace field in a file?**

For this task you can use awk. The output of the awk will be stored in a separate output file. Since you didn't give many details on your format I assumed there is a need to verify the 1st value is zero before changing it. You can omit the "if ($1 == 0)" part if it is not required.

```
awk '{ if ($1 == 0) { $1 = 20 } ; print $0 }' tt_bat_001.txt > tt_bat_001.out
```

**2) How to repeat a command for multiple files?**

You wrote you need to work on 100 files out of many, but you didn't explain how to distinguish the files need processing. Is it by filename? Is it by content? Other way?

So, 1st you need to generate a list of file. If it is be name, you can use find. If it is by content you can use grep. When you have the list you can use xargs to repeat the command for each file in your list. Here is an example using find for applying the command on "*.txt" files

```
find . -name '*.txt' | xargs -I % sh -c "awk '{ if (\$1 == 0) { \$1 = 20 } ; print \$0 }' % > %.out"
```

**3) How to apply the command on the source file?**

Since you can't read and overwrite the same file. You can mv the .out file and overwrite your source. You can achieve this by adding mv to the command

```
find . -name '*.txt' | xargs -I % sh -c "awk '{ if (\$1 == 0) { \$1 = 20 } ; print \$0 }' % > %.out ; mv %.out %"
```

Hope this helps :)